# How to input equations for Solve

Tags: equation-solving

I'm trying to input:

$$\log_{\sqrt 3}\frac{7-2x}{x+3}-\log_{\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}}(x+3)=\log_{\frac{1}{3}}9$$

My try:

`Solve Log[sqrt 3,(7-2x)/(x+3)]-Log[(1/(sqrt 3)),(x+3)]=Log[(1/3),9]`

I'm new in *Mathematica* so I'm not sure if my attempt is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Solve[Log[Sqrt[3], (7 - 2 x)/(x + 3)] - Log[1/Sqrt[3], (x + 3)] == 
  Log[1/3, 9], x]
```